# Spring 5 + Hibernate 5 Integration UnsatisfiedDependencyException Hproblem

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to spring I'm trying for several days to integrate Hibernate with Spring using annotations but I always get errors these my files:

When ever i run my project on firefox I get these errors

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in projects.onlineshopping.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1377)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:696)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:662)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:587)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:526)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in projects.onlineshopping.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1744)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1241)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1377)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The server time zone value '' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2293)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1740)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1241)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1377)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value '' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:255)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2303)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2289)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329)
      root cause

com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value '' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:128)
    com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2236)
    com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2260)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1314)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:963)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:255)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2303)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2289)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1740)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
```

and these my project files ...
pom.xml

```
    <properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql-connector.version>8.0.12</mysql-connector.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mysql connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- tomcat-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:component-scan base-package="projects.onlineshopping" ></context:component-scan>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

MainController.java

```
package projects.onlineshopping.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Created by @author Muhammed Alsaied On Sep 30, 2018
 * muhammadalsaied96@gmail.com
 */
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "index"})
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

HibernateConfig.java

```
package projects.onlineshopping.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * Created by @author Muhammed Alsaied On Sep 30, 2018
 * muhammadalsaied96@gmail.com
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("projects.onlineshopping.dto");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommerce");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Category.java

```
package projects.onlineshopping.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GeneratorType;

/**
 * Created by @author Muhammed Alsaied On Sep 30, 2018
 *  muhammadalsaied96@gmail.com
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;

    public Category(String name, String desc) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }


}
```

CategoryDAO.java

```
package projects.onlineshopping.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import projects.onlineshopping.dto.Category;

/**
 * Created by @author Muhammed Alsaied On Sep 30, 2018
 * muhammadalsaied96@gmail.com
 */

@Repository
public class CategoryDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public  void insert(Category category){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(category);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm from the logs the error is quite obvious : `Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution` and nested : `com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value '' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.`

Comment: @AntJavaDev thank you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying the server time zone in the connection string. This can be fixed by changing the connection string to:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommerce?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```